# How to include libraries in OSX bundles with CMAKE

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clion, dylib

Im trying to build an OSX bundle with Clion and Cmake, Currently the library links correctly in terms of I have no pre compile errors but when I build and try to run the program I get the following error

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: libxl.dylib
    Referenced from: 
    /path/to/executable/
      Reason: image not found
```

Ive searched on this issue and cant seem to find a clear solution, This is probably due to my lack of experience with CMake and C++.

If anyone has a solution or can point me in the direction of what I should be reading to further understand this it would be much appreciated.

See CMakeLists.txt below

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
    project(project name)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

    set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

    find_package( Qt5Core REQUIRED )
    find_package( Qt5Widgets REQUIRED )
    find_package( Qt5Gui REQUIRED )

    set(PROJECT_LINK_LIBS libxl.dylib)
    link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/LibXL/lib)
    include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/LibXL/include_cpp)


    #Mac Bundle (Built on Mac)
    add_executable(project_target_mac MACOSX_BUNDLE main.cpp)
    qt5_use_modules( project_target_mac Core Widgets Gui )
    target_link_libraries(project_target_mac Qt5::Widgets)
    target_link_libraries(project_target_mac ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} )
    #set_target_properties(project_target_mac PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/LibXL/lib")

    add_executable(project_target ${SOURCE_FILES})
    qt5_use_modules( project_target Core Widgets Gui )
    target_link_libraries(project_target Qt5::Widgets)
    target_link_libraries(project_target ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS

} )
```

Comment: I recently patched Tagaini Jisho project for this, may be you can use my pull request as example: https://github.com/Gnurou/tagainijisho/pull/195

Comment: Thanks I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

On OSX usually man uses Frameworks and integrate it into app bundle with an install rule.

The rule looks like:

```
    install( DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/ofxSyphon/libs/Syphon/lib/osx/Syphon.framework"
    DESTINATION ${APP_NAME}.app/Contents/Frameworks")
```

Then the framework folder will be copied into the `Contents/Frameworks` subfolder of the application bundle.
For this to work, the application itself should be installed with something like:

```
install(TARGETS ${APP_NAME} DESTINATION .)
```

And you might want to specify the installation prefix with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, default is `/usr/local`.

For a single library file, the process is quite similar, but you also have to tweak the `RPATH` of the application to add the relative path of the lib for the executable to find it. This part is not needed for framework because they have a standardized folder structure and the executable looks into it for its dependencies.